# How to handle the tap events in Push Notifications (Xamarin.IOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In xamarin.ios project I need to make specific alerts when user open the application by clicking on push notification.

In my current code I handle specific data `GUID, Type` of coming notification  of and using it to load data required for this notification (`LoadItemData`).
But I didn't find the way to handle the tap event, so if I have several notificaions in 1 time, clicking on any of these push notifications will have one result.

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{   
    if (uiapplication.sharedapplication.applicationstate.equals(uiapplicationstate.background))
    {
        string GUID = (userInfo[new NSString("Item_Guid")] as NSString).ToString();
        string Type = (userInfo[new NSString("Type")] as NSString).ToString();
        nsdictionary aps = userinfo.objectforkey(new nsstring("aps")) as nsdictionary;

        string alertinfo = string.empty;
        if (aps.containskey(new nsstring("alert")))
            alertinfo = (aps[new nsstring("alert")] as nsstring).tostring();

        var okcancelalertcontroller = uialertcontroller.create("New Notification", alertinfo, uialertcontrollerstyle.alert);
        okcancelalertcontroller.addaction(uialertaction.create("Open", uialertactionstyle.default, alert => LoadItemData(guid, type)));
        okcancelalertcontroller.addaction(uialertaction.create("OK", uialertactionstyle.cancel, alert => console.writeline("cancel was clicked")));
        uiapplication.sharedapplication.keywindow.rootviewcontroller.presentviewcontroller(okcancelalertcontroller, true, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lucas it is, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After iOS 10, Apple replaced `UIUserNotification`  with `UNNotification`.So use new Delegate in your app.

**For example**

in AppDelegate

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate,IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
...


[Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, System.Action completionHandler)
    {

        if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState==UIApplicationState.Active)
        {
            // app is active,do some thing you want
        }


        else
        {
            // app is in background ,do some thing you want
        }

        completionHandler();
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190947/xamarin-ios-local-push-notifications/52197386#52197386) that you can refer .