# How to show notification when app is updated from a data push message?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin forms ios app that is using the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin. I want to store data from a push notification and it seems that the only way to have it do something when the app is closed (Not in background) is to send a data message. This seems to work, I have a settings date that is updated when the app is closed but I don't get a notification. If I send a push notification with both data and notification I get a notification when the app is closed but the date is not updated. I am trying to figure out how to notify the user that the app data has updated from a data message but I am not sure of the proper way to do it. Would a local notification fired from a closed app be the proper way to solve this?

```
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("all");
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
    // Push message received event
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
    {
        ((AppShell)Application.Current.MainPage).DisplayPositiveToast($"Project updated {p.Data["myData"].ToString()}");
        Settings.LastCompletedSyncDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd h:mm tt");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":Received" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p.Data));
    };
```

Comment: Yes, you may need a local notification fired from a closed app, you can refer to this thread [Xamarin iOS Local Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190947/xamarin-ios-local-push-notifications).